# Collecting data via Array and copy it to another sheet in fixed order

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to set up a sheet that grabs data from Sheet 'input' and set it to Sheet 'output'.
This works fine for a row that only has one only value to return. However, some rows contain more than one value that needs to be returned.
For example,

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | Red |  |  |
| Car2 | Blue | Car3 | Yellow |
| Car4 | Green |  |  |

The desired outcome would be to grab the value (colour) and set it to the next available row on Sheet 'output', based on the pre-set order of Sheet 'input' e.g.

| Column A |
| --- |
| Red |
| Blue |
| Yellow |
| Green |

Piece of code down below;

```
function collectData()
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('input'); 
  var sOutput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('output'); 
  var endRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var firstCell = sOutput.getRange('A1').setValue('<start>');
        
  for (var i = 1; i <= endRow; i++)
{
 //car1 
if (ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()== 'car1' && ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != null )
{
 sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,2).getValue()); 
}
// car2
if else (ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()== 'car2' && ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != null )
{
  sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,2).getValue()); 
}
// car3 
if else (ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()== 'car3' && ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue() != null )
{
 sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()); 
}
else {}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions on this site should be specific, meaning that posts should contain only one question / should be about a single problem, issue or concern. Also instead of adding the complete code it's better to add a [mcve]. In the case of questions reading values from a spreadsheet it should include a brief description of the relevant parts of the spreadsheet, some sample data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: P.S. Whener be possible avoid the use of Google Apps Script methods like getRange inside a loop, use batch operations instead i.e. use `Sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` to read all the data range values at once.

Comment: You're absolutely right, apologies. Thank you pointing that out. I'll modify the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's how to get the data you want from input into output

I skipped a lot of your work with maxIndex and other stuff because I didn't want to take the time to figure it out.  But hopefully this will give you an example to assist you in accomplishing what you want.

```
function collectDataTest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ish = ss.getSheetByName('input');
  const ishsr = 2;//where data starts
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('output');
  osh.clear();
  const ivs = ish.getRange(ishsr,1,ish.getLastRow() - ishsr + 1, ish.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const lf = ['car1','car2','car3','car4'];
  let oA = [];
  ivs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let idx = lf.indexOf(r[0]);
    if(~idx && r[1]) {
      oA.push(r);
    }
  })
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

If you wish to use the value of lf in your result you may use lf[idx] to determine which it is.  If this doesn't assist you or if you wish me to delete it just let me know.

- [Bitwise Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: Many thanks Cooper, greatly appreciate it. I've got the set to next available row covered thanks to you. However, I still need to get the proper order set when multiple array value exist on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking in the wrong place. Just had to add '*getRange*' and follow it up by the required '*set.Value()*' within the same rows if statement:

So initial code was:

```
// car2
if else (ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()== 'car2' && ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != null )
{
  sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,2).getValue()); 
}
// car3 
if else (ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()== 'car3' && ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue() != null )
{
 sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()); 
}
```

Modified code is:

```
// car2 & 3
    if else (ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()== 'car2' && ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != null )
    {
      sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,2).getValue()); 
      sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sOutput.getRange(sOutput.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()); 
    }
```